# Limiting BART HuggingFace Model to complete sentences of maximum length

Tags: huggingface-transformers, summarization

I'm implementing BART on HuggingFace, see reference: https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bart.html

Here is the code from their documentation that works in creating a generated summary:

```
from transformers import BartModel, BartTokenizer, BartForConditionalGeneration

model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-cnn')
tokenizer = BartTokenizer.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large')

def baseBart(ARTICLE_TO_SUMMARIZE):
  inputs = tokenizer([ARTICLE_TO_SUMMARIZE], max_length=1024, return_tensors='pt')
  # Generate Summary
  summary_ids = model.generate(inputs['input_ids'], num_beams=4, max_length=25, early_stopping=True)
  return [tokenizer.decode(g, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=False) for g in summary_ids][0]
```

I need to impose conciseness with my summaries so I am setting `max_length=25`. In doing so though, I'm getting incomplete sentences such as these two examples:

> EX1: The opacity at the left lung base appears stable from prior exam.
> There is elevation of the left hemidi
>
> EX 2: There is normal mineralization and alignment. No fracture or
> osseous lesion is identified. The ankle mort

How do I make sure that the predicted summary is only coherent sentences with complete thoughts and remains concise. If possible, I'd prefer to not perform a regex on the summarized output and cut off any text after the last period, but actually have the BART model produce sentences within the the maximum length.

I tried setting `truncation=True` in the model but that didn't work.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question but I believe max_length refers to the length of the input encoding (e.g. 25 tokens with padding if less than 25), not the desired output summary length.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this @rocket_boomerang_19?

Comment: @Mendhak I did not; never solved this for the output generation.